# Why does my motherboard not pick up PATA HDD using a SATA adaptor?

Tags: bios, sata, pata

I've connected the adapter to the PATA drive (40 pin).
Powered the PATA drive using standard Molex.
Slotted the small 4 pin cable (branches off the Molex cable) into the adapter - I believe this powers the PCB / adapter itself (?). Hooked up the adapter to my motherboard's 5th SATA2 port.

The drive itself spins up normally and remains spinning, although it does **lag POST by about 20 seconds or so (whilst it's trying to detect drives)**. I've taken this PATA drive out of my old computer and know that it works. There's no clicking or obvious mechanical malfunction.

I've removed the jumper which, according to the label on the drive, means it will *slave* (although slave/master state shouldn't matter, right?).

BIOS reports:

```
SATA 5: [Not Detected]
```

*I'm slightly clueless...*

My specifications:

- **Motherboard:**
      ASUS P6X58D-E
- **HDD:**
      Maxtor 120GB IDE PATA
- **PATA -> SATA adapter:**
      [SATA to IDE convertor](http://www.maplin.co.uk/sata-to-ide-convertor-36036)

[image]

Comment: I guess the first thing to try is making the hard drive master, to see if it does matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good now!

I **set the jumper to master on the PATA drive** and plugged the other end of the SATA cable into a different port. I was previously using port 5 and had port 4 empty, so I moved this over to port 4.

Most probably the jumper switch that did it - as recommended by Col, in a comment on the question.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You should mark this as the correct answer. =)

Comment: @Lukasa - I tried to, but I have to wait 2 days since it's my own answer ;)